# disconnecting mapped drive vb

Tags: vb.net, webdav, disconnect, mapped-drive

i have mapped a network drive using a function that finds next available letter drive and then maps it using net use z: \server\z , how do i disconnect all network drives and not just specifically z ? thank you for any help . p.s. i'm new to all this :)

```
    Dim alphabet As New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()


    Dim lowerBound As Integer = Convert.ToInt16("g"c)
    Dim upperBound As Integer = Convert.ToInt16("z"c)
    For i As Integer = lowerBound To upperBound - 1
        Dim driveLetter As Char = ChrW(i)
        alphabet.Add(driveLetter.ToString())
    Next

    lowerBound = Convert.ToInt16("a"c)
    upperBound = Convert.ToInt16("i"c)
    For i As Integer = lowerBound To upperBound - 1
        Dim driveLetter As Char = ChrW(i)
        alphabet.Add(driveLetter.ToString())
    Next

    ' get all current drives
    Dim drives As System.IO.DriveInfo() = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    For Each drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In drives
        alphabet.Remove(drive.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower())
    Next

    For Each s As String In alphabet
        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(s) = False Then
            Return s
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: anyone know what the proper format of net use z: /delete/yes ? i can't get it to persistently to answer yes

Answer (score 1):

```
net use z: \\server\z /delete
```

Im sure there is a better site than this but this one works: [Net Use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: net use z: \\server\z /delete /yes